# openvpn route-up script no mount permissions

Tags: mount, openvpn, bind-mount

I'm trying to mount a couple of nfs shares after my openvpn tunnel is up. Previously this worked on ubuntu 12.04 and ubuntu 14.04. I made a clean install with ubuntu 16.04 and can't get it to work.

To simplify testing I use the current mount script to figure out why things don't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "mounting testdir.."
echo "I am:" `whoami`
echo `id`
/bin/mount -v --bind /mnt/testdir1 /mnt/testdir2-mountbind/
echo "testdir mounted!"
```

When I execute this from the command line it works:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo /mnt/mounttest.sh 
mounting testdir..
I am: root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
mount: /mnt/testdir1 bound on /mnt/testdir2-mountbind.
testdir mounted!
xxx@xxx:~$
```

However, when I configure this as `route-up /mnt/mounttest.sh` in my openvpn I get a permission denied error. I suspect that this is also the problem when I try to mount nfs shares but they simply hang and don't give me any extra info. Openvpn output/log:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo service openvpn@xxx start
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo tail /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.xxx.log 
Sun Nov 27 10:37:56 2016 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sun Nov 27 10:37:56 2016 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.20.31.94 peer 10.20.31.93
Sun Nov 27 10:37:56 2016 /sbin/ip route add 10.20.30.0/24 via 10.20.31.93
Sun Nov 27 10:37:56 2016 /sbin/ip route add 10.20.31.0/24 via 10.20.31.93
mounting testdir..
I am: root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
mount: permission denied
testdir mounted!
Sun Nov 27 10:37:56 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
xxx@xxx:~$
```

Comment: I experience a very similar problem on FreeBSD (FreeNAS) - trying to get my route-up script to talk to my torrent program by a call to some binary. However, instead of a direct "permission denied" error, in my case it looks like the whole call is ignored...