# OpenVPN start script does not execute a command

Tags: freebsd, openvpn

**Background**: I'm configuring Transmission (v2.93) and OpenVPN (v2.4.6) in a jail (a FreeNAS 11.1 plugin jail) and want to add an `--up` script to OpenVPN which will request Transmission to change its listening port (using `transmission-remote` program).

My `openvpn.conf` contains the following (among others):

```
verb 4
script-security 2
up /usr/local/etc/openvpn/set_port.sh
up-restart ;only to make the up script be executed on restarts
           ;but disabling this changes nothing
```

and the `set_port.sh` script contains (a minimal script that still reproduces the behavior):

```bash
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/transmission-remote --auth rpc_user:rpc_pass -p 6666 2>&1 > output.txt
echo 'the script itself runs: '$(pwd) $(whoami) > status.txt
```

The script has all permissions (777) and the binary (`transmission-remote`) has all the permissions. I am aware the path to binary is actually a soft link, so I replaced it with the actual path (`/usr/pbi/transmission-amd64/.sbin/transmission-remote`) but the behavior I observe is the same.

**Problem**: when I start OpenVPN (`service openvpn start`), *the script itself* is executed, but the actual command fails mysteriously: the port is not being assigned (verified by looking through [Transmission Remote GUI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/transgui/) and the command generates empty output.
Contents of the debug files are as follows:
`output.txt` is empty (with and without *stderr* redirection)
`status.txt` says as expected: `the script itself runs: /usr/local/etc/openvpn root`.

However, when I run this script manually (`./set_port.sh`), said command completes successfully: `output.txt` will say `localhost:9091/transmission/rpc/ responded: "success"` and the port will be changed.

What am I missing?

**Similar** to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/), except I am not getting any "permission denied" messages - it seems like the command is not even executed (if I `echo $(<that command>) > file.txt`, I get an empty file).
[This one](https://superuser.com/questions/925576/) is also somewhat related, but the OP is asking about `--client-connect` and eventually solves the issue by writing full paths to the programs they want to run - this did not help in my case (but if I `echo $(ls /usr/local/bin) > log.txt`, the list of binaries is correct).

**Update** per @roaima's request. I changed the `set_port.sh` to the following:

```bash
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
exec >debug.txt 2>&1
set -x
echo script is running
/usr/pbi/transmission-amd64/.sbin/transmission-remote  --auth rpc_user:rpc_pass -p 6666 2>&1 > output.txt
```

then rinsed and repeated. The `debug.txt` file contained these lines:

```
+ echo script is running
script is running
+ /usr/pbi/transmission-amd64/.sbin/transmission-remote --auth rpc_user:rpc_pass -p 12345
/usr/local/etc/openvpn/test.sh: line 5:  6795 Segmentation fault      /usr/pbi/transmission-amd64/.sbin/transmission-remote --auth rpc_user:rpc_pass -p 12345 2>&1 > output.txt
```

Comment: Does the `output.txt` file get created, or did you previously create it before the script ran? What directory is the script running from (can you use absolute paths eg `/tmp/output.txt`)? What if you send _stderr_ to the file too (`/path/to/command >/tmp/output.txt 2>&1`)?

Comment: Every time I restart the service, I also run a cleaning script to make sure those files (`output.txt`, `status.txt`) don't exist. And every time they are created: output is empty, status correctly reporting the user is `root` and the directory called from (`$(pwd)`) is exactly where the `set_port.sh` is. Redirecting stderr changes nothing. I updated the original post with this information.

Comment: Please insert these commands as the second, third and fourth lines of your script: `exec >debug.txt 2>&1` and `set -x` and `echo script is running`. Put the contents of `debug.txt` into your question.

Comment: Fixed. I misunderstood you initially, now did what you requested. It revealed that I'm getting a segfault at the call to the binary! But why would it occur only when calling the script from OpenVPN? If I run manually, no such thing occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the line

```
/usr/local/etc/openvpn/test.sh: line 5:  6795 Segmentation fault      /usr/pbi/transmission-amd64/.sbin/transmission-remote --auth rpc_user:rpc_pass -p 12345 2>&1 > output.txt
```

It looks like your executables have got mismatched libraries. Please recheck how you've built your chroot. (I haven't used FreeBSD for years and years so I can't give you pointers on how to do that, sorry.)

Comment: I'm not running chroot - at least I did not configure anything like that. The whole setup is running in a jail, which to my understanding is not the same. I'll try to research the libraries thing and see what I can dig up.

Comment: `ldd` says that transmission-remote only requires `libc.so.7`. Now I see that the file that resides within my jail's `/lib/` is different to the one that lies in my main root (1744304 vs 1671232 bytes). Could this be of any significance?

Comment: @PrzemekD Yes definitely

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the library mismatch that is going on here, especially that it all happens in a FreeNAS "plugin jail" and I don't know how it is configured. However, I have managed to work around the issue in order to achieve the goal of having OpenVPN configure Transmission at route-up.
**Note**: the following answer does NOT solve the segmentation fault issue, so I am not going to mark it as accepted.

The solution is based on the following observation: while `transmission-remote` segfaulted if called by OpenVPN, it ran perfectly fine if `cron` called it instead:

1. Leave `openvpn.conf` as is.
2. In `set_port.sh`, instead of calling `transmission-remote`, store the port number in a file - for example like this: `echo $port > $path/port-id` (from here on I will assume variable `path` leads to the folder where we store the scripts etc.)
3. Make a new script, let's call it `actually_set.sh`, with the following:

```bash
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
if [ -f $path/port-id ]; then
  port=$(cat $path/port-id)
  rm $path/port-id
  transmission-remote -n 'rpc_user:rpc_pass' -p $port
fi
```

4. Set `cron` to call the above script every minute. I put the following in my crontab:
   `* * * * * /usr/local/etc/openvpn/ports/tp_setter.sh`

Answer (score -1):

If you set your `verb` level to 3-4, you probably should see warnings about scripts not being run. By default, OpenVPN 2.2+ only calls certain built-ins. You need to relax this using [`script-security`:](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage)

> `--script-security level`
>
> This directive offers policy-level control over OpenVPN's usage of external programs and scripts. Lower level
>   values are more restrictive, higher values are more permissive.
>
> Settings for level:
>
> `0` -- Strictly no calling of external programs.
>   `1` -- (Default) Only call built-in executables such as ifconfig, ip, route, or netsh.
>   `2` -- Allow calling of built-in executables and user-defined scripts.
>   `3` -- Allow passwords to be passed to scripts via environmental variables (potentially unsafe).

You need to make sure that you have `script-security` set to 2 or 3 (2 if you don't need to send passwords to the script, 3 otherwise.)

Comment: I am already running `script-security 2` - the script wouldn't be launched without it. The problem is that it launches but ignores this particular command. Setting `verb 4` shows nothing unusual: `tun` device is opened, `ifconfig` sets something up, then my script is executed, then some routes are added and initialization sequence completes. My script does run, as confirmed by `echo`ing from within it - but whenever I make a call to `transmission-remote`, it is ignored.

Comment: As it's running in a jail. the only other thing I can think of is that possibly access to `localhost` or some file is being blocked. Do you get any error messages if you redirect both standard output and error (i.e. `transmission-remote ... >messages.txt 2>&1`)?

Comment: The output is empty even with `2>&1` - it is as if there was no such binary file. I tried executing some non-existent binary and the result was the same. Except that if I `ls`, said binary exists. (I'll update the question to contain this additional info.)

Comment: Very strange. The only other thing I can think of is to make sure that all the shared libraries (`.so`) are accessible if `transmission-remote` isn't statically linked. I would have thought that missing libraries would be reported, however.